# Restroom facilities near Saint Chad's Well (Sacred Spring in England)

Tags: uk, hygiene, england, accessibility

A visitor to the UK wants to visit the sacred spring associated with Saint Chad ([Chadwell Heath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chadwell_Heath) -- Not the other ones in Mercia and Lichfield and Staffordshire) for its reputed healing and spiritual nourishment powers.  See [Megalithic](http://www.megalithic.co.uk/article.php?sid=18532) for details.

The spring is on public land, but there are no public toilet facilities in the immediate area.  Where would the nearest public toilet facility be that someone could use?  Assume normal day time hours.  Night and bank holidays can be excluded, but something open on bank holidays would be gratefully received.

**Adding...**

Owing to commentary, a photo is now added...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google shows a pub [The Harrow](http://www.allinlondon.co.uk/clubs_bars/venue-5637.php)* 0.6 miles north east, more or less on the 296 bus route (every 20 min).

```
*Opening Hours: 
Mon:    11:00 - 23:00
Tue:    11:00 - 23:00
Wed:    11:00 - 23:00 
Thu:    11:00 - 23:00 
Fri:    11:00 - 23:00 
Sat:    11:00 - 23:00 
Sun:    12:00 - 22:30
```

Your image is distinctly more impressive than this one (from Google Maps)!:

[image: TSE45787 example]

Comment: +1, Good point about the Megalithic link.  I will add a photo to help improve the question.

Answer (score 4):

From checking [Great British Toilet Map](http://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/), the nearest toilets to St Chad's Well appear to be:

- [Marks Gate Cemetery](http://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/54c2347a2ec4abe957b83a76), open Summer (April - September): 08.00 - 18.30 / Winter (October-March): 08.00 - 16.00, no charge. About 2km from the well.

Other nearby toilets are at [St Chad's Park](http://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/54c2347a2ec4abe957b83a7a) or [Wangey Road](http://greatbritishpublictoiletmap.rca.ac.uk/loos/54c2352f2ec4abe957b8587c).